# JUnit tests always pass when executing in device

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, android-testing

This simple test

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class Test {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        assert(false)
    }

}
```

Unexpectedly, this passes when put in `androidTest` (both through Android Studio and in the terminal), but obviously fails as expected when put in `test`.

Comment: `assert()` is a primitive function that is controlled by your run time assert settings. Try using `org.junit.Asserts.assertTrue()` to check that assertion.

Comment: @BobDalgleish You're correct, that solved the problem (with `org.junit.Assert.assertTrue`). Is there any way I can set the assertion on on runtime?

Comment: Use the -ea command line option to enable assertions. However, I strongly recommend using the JUnit assertions instead.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Yes, thanks you. I wrapped JUnit `assert` in a Kotlin `assert { }`. If you put that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use JUnit assertions for running tests. The base `assert()` functionality is normally disabled when running "production" code, so you cannot depend that a plain `assert` statement will throw an assertion exception.

Use:

```
org.junit.Asserts.assertTrue( false )
```

to make the test fail properly.

Answer (score 1):

I just fall on same issue, on a newer version of `junit` I then used quite the same code as [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629560/11159476) with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(false)` but IntelliJ told me there is a simpler method with:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail();
```